# Anlysing branch prediction accuracy with certain pipelinedepth

Tags: testing, simulator, pipeline, branch-prediction

Currently I'm studying about branch prediction accuracy and the relation with pipelinedepth and/or using parallel fetching (f.e. in superscalar processors). Is it possible to analyse this relationship with the use of software? I was thinking about using zesto ([Link](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4919638)) and the sim-bpred simulator ([http://www.ece.uah.edu/~lacasa/tutorials/ss/ss.htm#sim-bpred](http://www.ece.uah.edu/%7Elacasa/tutorials/ss/ss.htm#sim-bpred)). And working with metrics like IPC (#instructions per cycle).
What are the (dis)advantages of using these? Or is there any other (good) way for doing analysis on this topic?